# How to extract the same and highest value?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a table like below, I like to extract rows if they have the same value in the rows 4 and 8 otherwise the maximum value.

```
Input: data

1   9708  10948  1  1   9708  10948  1
1  11590  18647  4  1  12897  15040  2
1  11590  18647  4  1  15040  15500  3
1  11590  18647  4  1  15950  16580  2
1 108570 109500  1  1 108570 109500  1
1 440900 443400  2  1 440900 441080  1
1 440900 443400  2  1 443140 443400  1
1 539670 542200  3  1 539700 540450  2
1 539670 542200  3  1 541070 541770  2
1 539670 542200  3  1 540450 541070  3
1 712695 715758 14  1 712799 712900  5
1 712695 715758 14  1 713010 713230  8
1 751500 759199  8  1 752555 752773  5
1 761083 764000  9  1 761083 761198  1
1 761083 764000  9  1 762200 762300  8
1 761083 764000  9  1 762300 762800  9



ideal Output:

1   9708  10948  1  1   9708  10948  1
1  11590  18647  4  1  15040  15500  3
1 108570 109500  1  1 108570 109500  1
1 440900 443400  2  1 440900 441080  1
1 440900 443400  2  1 443140 443400  1
1 539670 542200  3  1 540450 541070  3
1 712695 715758 14  1 713010 713230  8
1 751500 759199  8  1 752555 752773  5
1 761083 764000  9  1 762300 762800  9
```

I have tried two commands, the first one gives me the same value between columns 4 and 8, but I want something like the second one and ideal Output.

```
data<-data[which(data$V4 == data$V8),]

data<- data[ifelse(data$V4 == data$V8,data$V4,max(data$V8)),]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question? Why is the second row in your desired output?
The fourth and eight column are not equal, and they are also not "the maximum value"

Comment: Why is the result only a subset of the original data.frame? I also do not understand exactly the logic behind the output as cettt already stated.

Comment: @Cett, the second row, due to there is not the same value "4" in column 4 and 8 I like to have the maximum value for that (column 5 to 7 have overlap with column 1 to 3)

Comment: @DSGym, my original file is really huge, so I select a subset of them.

Comment: What do you mean "the maximum value"? In which column? So for each number in column 4 you want to keep the rows where column 8 is equal to it, or, if there is no equal number in row 8, keep the row where the value of column 8 is the highest?

Comment: @iod, yes I want to keep the rows that have the same value in column 4 and 8, and if there is not the equal value I like to keep that rows with the maximum value (e.g, for the rows 2 to 4, there is not equal value but the maximum value for those rows in column 8 is number 3 so I like to keep it as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the op want to group by `V3`, so the approach should be `group_by` `V3` first then filter on your condition.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(V3) %>% 
  filter(V4 == V8 | (V4 == max(V4) & V8 == max(V8)))


# A tibble: 9 x 8
# Groups:   V3 [8]
     V1     V2     V3    V4    V5     V6     V7    V8
  <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
1     1   9708  10948     1     1   9708  10948     1
2     1  11590  18647     4     1  15040  15500     3
3     1 108570 109500     1     1 108570 109500     1
4     1 440900 443400     2     1 440900 441080     1
5     1 440900 443400     2     1 443140 443400     1
6     1 539670 542200     3     1 540450 541070     3
7     1 712695 715758    14     1 713010 713230     8
8     1 751500 759199     8     1 752555 752773     5
9     1 761083 764000     9     1 762300 762800     9
```

Comment: How did you figure V3 works into this? I mean, your result appears to be accurate, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: @iod, I compared with data inputs and desired outputs and guess that's what op wants. Or maybe `group_by(V2, V3)`, or `group_by(V2)` since `V2`, and `V3` both seem to be identifiers (or 1 on 1). I have to guess since op did not provide the meaning of the variables.

Comment: It looks to me like there's a lot of IDs, but why not just group by V4? Also, what happens if max(V8) is bigger than V4? Then you'll get both V4==V8 and max(V8) rows.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
bind_rows(
  filter(group_by(data,V4), !any(V4==V8),V8==max(V8)), 
  filter(group_by(data,V4), any(V4==V8),V4==V8)
)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 8
# Groups:   V4 [7]
     V1     V2     V3    V4    V5     V6     V7    V8
  <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
1     1  11590  18647     4     1  15040  15500     3
2     1 440900 443400     2     1 440900 441080     1
3     1 440900 443400     2     1 443140 443400     1
4     1 712695 715758    14     1 713010 713230     8
5     1 751500 759199     8     1 752555 752773     5
6     1   9708  10948     1     1   9708  10948     1
7     1 108570 109500     1     1 108570 109500     1
8     1 539670 542200     3     1 540450 541070     3
9     1 761083 764000     9     1 762300 762800     9
```

You can probably do the same in base R with split. The idea is you split the data into groups based on the value of V4, and then you select the groups where there's any case of V4==V8 and pull that row from it, and the groups where there's no such case, and then you pull from there the row(s) where V8 is the max.